# Is there any reference to the existence of platypuses in Zootopia?

Tags: zootopia

**Zootopia** is in a world where only mammals evolved, although there are some mammals missing specially the primates and domesticated animals such like the dogs and cats.

I came across a doubt about the existence of platypuses in the Zootopia universe, specially since it's a mammal that lays eggs.

Is there any reference to the existence of platypuses in Zootopia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes, but only in secondary canon.

In the film itself (primary canon), there are no platypuses. But the "expanded universe" novel [*The Stinky Cheese Caper and Other Cases from the ZPD Files*](http://zootopia.wikia.com/wiki/The_Stinky_Cheese_Caper_and_Other_Cases_from_the_ZPD_Files), in which Judy and Nick visit the Australian-themed Outback Island, features a platypus named [Singcor Swim](http://zootopia.wikia.com/wiki/Singcor_Swim) (ha ha).

<sub>I found this answer by Googling "zootopia platypus", which led me first to [this page](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Species_seen_in_Zootopia), confirming that platypuses *do* appear somewhere in Zootopia canon, and then to [this page](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:650257), which pointed me to the relevant book.</sub>